# Load another form in Visual foxpro

Tags: forms, visual-foxpro

Visual foxpro 9

I have Form1, contain button btnFind; and Form2, now I want to when button btnFind is clicked, Form2 is showing up, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the click of the button on the first form, just call the second with...

Do form Form2

Now, if you wanted to pass a parameter to the second form, you wound need to add a "parameter" statement to the load event of the second form and then...

do form Form2 with SomeParameterValue

Comment: So, Can I pass multiple parameter to form2, and how to retrieve them?

Comment: That's a separate question and you should mark this one as answered by DRapp and create another for your multiple parameters query.

Comment: @verdana, as Alan mentioned, above... mark this one as answered and post other as a new question.